# Spring mvc - jsp MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to catch a parameter from a MYSQL DB and print it on a JSP page through spring mvc.

I have the following function in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showentry")
public ModelAndView showentry(@RequestParam("id") String id){
    System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" + id);
    entries = dao.search(id);
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("list", entries);
    return mav;
}
```

that get the parameter "Id" from the following form:

```
  <form action="showentry">
    <input type=  "hidden" name="id" value = "${item.id}">
    <button> Show Entry </button>
  </form>
```

the function that calls the showentry method is in a DAO class:

```
@Override
public List<Entry> search(String id) {
    List<Entry> res = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Id = ? ;";
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try {
        //open connection
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();

        //prepare the statement
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        //bind parameters to preparedstatement
        ps.setString(1, id);

        //execute the statement
        resultSet = ps.executeQuery(sql);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Entry entry = new Entry();
            entry.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            entry.setCn(resultSet.getString("cn"));
            entry.setSn(resultSet.getString("sn"));
            entry.setPn(resultSet.getString("pn"));
            res.add(entry);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        //[...]
    }
    return res;
}
```

I can print on the logs the string with the id related to the entry, for example: 
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 32

But it doesn't print on the jsp, and it returns an error:

```
net.tirasa.springaddressbook.SpringEntryDAO search
GRAVE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

Is there something wrong with the sql string ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the patameter in `resultSet = ps.executeQuery(sql);`

it must be

```
resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
```

See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)) from the method `executeQuery(String sql)`:

> Note:This method cannot be called on a PreparedStatement or
>   CallableStatement

Also remove the `;` at the end of your statement:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Id = ?";
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing semicolon inside the sql

String sql = "SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Id = ? **;**";